# Change color of an image using ngStyle

Tags: html, css, angular, angular5

I am sorry if this question sounds very naive but i am new to Angular 5. I need to change the color of an image based on the color code i am getting from my JSON response. I searched but i only found how to change background color. I couldn't find any examples.

Below is my json response snippet:

```
{"medDetailsEve":{"color":"#800000","medDate":"04/27/2018","medTime":"20:00","medId":"PE16","sequence":"EVEN","shape":"2","status":""}}
```

Below is the code i am trying

```
<img src="./assets/img/tab/{{data.shape}}.png" style="-webkit-filter: opacity(.5) drop-shadow(0 0 0 {{data.color}}) class="pill-img">"
```

Comment: Are you still looking or did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

In style attribute I think you are missing `;` between opacity and drop-shadow:

```
style="-webkit-filter: opacity(.5); drop-shadow(0 0 0 {{data.color}})"
```

Comment: i tried  but still color is not applying in the image.

Comment: Can you paste the browser rendered code for drop-shadow value?

Comment: i can'not share the code as it is confidential. Sorry.

Comment: Not the application code, but what you see when you inspect in the browser to check if the syntax is correct and you get the value from json in the template correctly, do you see drop-shadow(0 0 0 #800000)" when you inspect in your browser?

Comment: i see this `<img _ngcontent-c1="" class="pill-img" src="./assets/img/tab/2.png" style="">`

Comment: when i am hard coding the 4th parameter of drop-shadow i get `<img _ngcontent-c1="" class="pill-img" style="-webkit-filter: opacity(.5); drop-shadow(0 0 0 #800000)" src="./assets/img/tab/2.png">`

Comment: So your styles are not being applied at all, remove filter for the moment and check if you are getting the data.color value correctly in the template.

Comment: i am getting the value as i can see it when i do <p>{{data.color}}</p>

Answer (score 1):

Use ngStyle with concatenation:

```
<img ... [ngStyle]="{'-webkit-filter': 'opacity(.5) drop-shadow(0 0 0 '+data.color}">
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yssbfd)